# Custom Django Forms (crispy)

Tags: python, django, custom-fields

I have a registration form, I'm using crispy. I want to make the input fields look better so I wanted to add a class to each of them but the site only renders the first input field with the class. (This is my first django project so I'm pretty new to this)

Here's my forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm



class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),

        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),

        'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),

        'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control input'}),

        

    }
```

Here's the template:

```
<div class="sign-up">
   

<form class="form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4, sign-up__header">Join Today</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
#override
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #Custom classok
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input'
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input'
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input'
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'input'
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Row, Column



class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column('username', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0 input'),
                Column('email', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0 input'),
                Column('password1', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0 input'),
                Column('password2', css_class='form-group col-md-3 mb-0 input'),
                css_class='form-row'
            )
        )
```

More details please refer this [document](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html)

Comment: I tried this, but still it only applies the styles on the username field